# Cannot print value from nested class with ArrayList

Tags: java, html, templates, nested, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker 2.3.23 to generate report.
Below is the def of class I used:

```
public class result{
    public ArrayList<Table> expected;
    public ArrayList<Table> actual;
    public ArrayList<Table> result;
    public ArrayList<Stat> stat_list;

    public result(){
        expected=new ArrayList<Table>();
        actual=new ArrayList<Table>();
        result=new ArrayList<Table>();
        stat_list=new ArrayList<Stat>();
    }
    public ArrayList<Table> getexpected(){
        return expected;
    }
    public ArrayList<Table> getactual(){
        return actual;
    }
    public ArrayList<Table> getresult(){
        return result;
    }
    public ArrayList<Stat> getstat_list(){
        return stat_list;
    }
}

public class Table{
    public ArrayList<Row> contents;//First row in the table would be for the header.
    public HashMap<String,Integer> Col_Index_Map;//Column Header->Column Index Mapping
    public Table(){
        contents=new ArrayList<Row>();
        Col_Index_Map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    }
    public ArrayList<Row> getcontents(){
        return contents;
    }
    public HashMap<String,Integer> getCol_Index_Map(){
        return Col_Index_Map;
    }
}

public class Row {
    public ArrayList<Cell> fields;
    public int rowNo;
    public Row(){
        fields=new ArrayList<Cell>();
        rowNo=0;
    }
    public ArrayList<Cell> getfields(){
        return fields;
    }
    public int getrowNo(){
        return rowNo;
    }
}

public class Cell {
    public ArrayList<String> data;
    public Cell(){
        data=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getdata(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

And I used below template to print every element in the cell that is in the table. But got no output at all the report generated is empty html:
I tried with 2 layers nested class and it was working but not this case.

```
<#list expected as expected_table>
   <h2>Result Table:</h2>
   <table class='table table-bordered reportStyle'>
      <td>
         <#list expected_table.contents as expected_row>
            <tr>
                <#list expected_row.fields as expected_cell>
                    <#list expected_cell.data as expected_item>
                        ${expected_item}
                    </#list>                      
                </#list>        
            </tr>
        </#list>
        </td>
      </table>          
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code should work. The reason it didn't work is because of wrong assignment to the fields which is not listed in the above code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: _should work_ or really _works_? Because some frameworks (I am not sure whether Freemarker, too) have problems when the getter method is `getfield()` instead of `getField()` - the camel-case naming requirement comes from the JavaBean specification.

Comment: It really works. I am using getfield() for each field I need to have access from freemarker. And I'm getting all the value from those fields correctly. Didn't try getField() though.